# Django webserver automatically shuts off on local server when I try to access the admin section

Tags: django

I'm a noob trying to learn Django for the first time, I created a project in a virtualenv on Windows 10. It worked well in the beginning where I was able to login to the admin section after running '''python manage.py runserver'''

But now when I run the same command I'm able to see the Django landing page but as soon as I try to hit http://localhost:8000/admin/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin the server automatically disconnects and I get the "This site can’t be reached" error on Chrome.

I tried changing the port number by running `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001` but it didn't work. I tried to check if the port (8000) is currently in use by running the cmd (as an admin) `netstat -a -b` but couldn't find any issues.

The server just quits without any error message

Edit: Currently using Python 3.7.0 and django-3.0.1

[image]

Comment: what is the django and python version?

Comment: I'm currently using Python 3.7.0 and django-3.0.1

Comment: It is django 3.0 issue. You should downgrade your django version.

Comment: I'll try downgrading and will get back to this thread with an update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a ticket about this issue: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31067.

This seems to be a bug in Python 3.7.0, and appears to be fixed in Python 3.7.1. It's still unknown what the exact trigger is for this bug.

Since Django officially only supports the latest patch release of a Python series, this won't be fixed in Django. You can either upgrade your Python version to the latest patch release of 3.7, or downgrade Django to 2.2.

Comment: Thank you! this was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Django 3.0 issue as I've seen. There are so many issues on GitHub, regarding this error.

You may try downgrading to Django 2.* versions for now. Version 2.1/2.2 works fine.